# Rsync - preserve owner/group metadata, but not as local users

Tags: rsync

I want to `rsync` my server to back up its content. I want to preserve owner/group so that I can later restore the server using the backup. However the server has a different set of users and groups than my local machine, so it doesn't make sense to use native users. I also don't want to run `rsync` as a root because of security implications. How can I do it?

Comment: `--fake-super --numeric-ids` seem promising, but need testing.

Comment: --numeric-ids does need root permissions on the receiver site

Comment: What are your security troubles?

Comment: If  your server is able to automatically login as root on backuphost to "push" backups then it would feel a bit dangerous that an intruder on server could destroy both the server plus backuphost.

Comment: This is (one of) the reason(s) why a pure rsync solution is not a professional backup solution. I'm voting to move your question to Unix/Linux instead; if anyone knows of a way to fix this, they're likely to hang out over there.

Comment: To lower the security risk I "pull" the update from the backup host and restrict the root ssh login on server read-only via ```/root/.ssh/authorized_keys```: ```command="/usr/local/bin/rrsync -ro /" ssh-rsa ...```

Answer (score 3):

You could write a script which saves permissions, user, group per file, maybe just like

`getfacl -R / > /tmp/permissions.txt`

to be restored if needed by

`setfacl --restore=permissions.txt`

Then rsync everything including permissions.txt to a normal user account on the backup host.

The downside is that permissions.txt may not be 100% synchron to the actual backup.

Note saving secret files with wrong permissions under a normal user account might be also a security issue! At least the directory containing the whole backup should be readable only by the backup user.

One more security note: permissions.txt on the original host should be also protected, readable only by root.

Answer (score 1):

I can't offer a solution that doesn't run as root but I can offer the following:

First, if you use `--numeric-ids` it will preserve the UID/GIDs.  If you do a restore with `rsync` or `tar` (or anything that doesn't mess with UID/GIDs) you'll be fine.

```
rsync -avP --numeric-ids
```

However not running as root is going to be a problem because Unix requires `root` to create files as another user. You might be able to use selinux to give the command permissions to write any file, but that is rather complex (though `--fake-super` will help)

Would it meet your security requirements if the backup server used root and the other side didn't?

```
# run this on the backup host:
rsync -avP --numeric-ids user@SOURCEHOST:/path/to/files/. /path/to/dest/.
```

As long as root@BACKUPHOST can ssh to user@SOURCEHOST, you'll be fine.  Well, mostly fine.  If `user` can't access a file, it won't get backuped.  Depending on your situation, that may not be an issue.

Comment: BTW you may also restrict the "pull backup key" in authorized_keys to one particular rsync command only or more generic to read-only rsync (google: ```rrsync```)